# Combine javascript filters with jqPagination

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqpagination

I am using javascript to filter elements on a page using show/hide.  I would like to use jqPagination with this as well.  The problem is that jqPagination also uses show/hide.  So if a user clicks a filter link it will hide a number of the elements on the page and only show them the filtered results.  I would then like jqPagination to paginate only the filtered results and not all the elements on the page anymore.  This may not be possible, but maybe there is another strategy for combining filtering with paginating?

Comment: I ended up using angularjs instead of jqPagination to solve this problem.